# Drop columns in a data.frame by sum of levels in R

Tags: r, subset

this problem is annoying because I'm searching for an answer this whole morning and I know that the answer must be very simple.

I have a df with multiple factors or variables (more than in this example) and only two levels:

```
row.name  Factor1 Factor2 Factor3 Factor4
1         dog     dog     cat     cat
2         dog     dog     cat     dog
3         dog     cat     dog     dog
4         dog     cat     dog     dog
```

Now, I just want to drop these columns that contain **dog** and **cat** > 1

```
row.name  Factor2 Factor3
1         dog     cat
2         dog     cat
3         cat     dog
4         cat     dog
```

This must be very easy, but I can't find the right solution. I can already drop the columns that contain only one level but not those columns with two levels but with only one occurrence of one level.

Any help is very appreciated.

*edit

Both approaches from Ryan worked for me after a slight change. The original solutions kept only the columns that contained only **dog**, e.g. Factor1

```
row.name  Factor1
1         dog
2         dog
3         dog
4         dog
```

Hence, I changed it in this way:

```
df %>% 
  select_if(~ !is.factor(.x) | sum(tabulate(.x) > 1) >= 2)
```

and

```
df[, sapply(df, function(x) !is.factor(x) | sum(tabulate(x) > 1) >= 2)]
```

Both ways are working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `tabulate` rather than `table`, which should be faster

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select_if(~ !is.factor(.x) | sum(tabulate(.x) > 1) <= 1)

#   row.name Factor1 Factor4
# 1        1     dog     cat
# 2        2     dog     dog
# 3        3     dog     dog
# 4        4     dog     dog
```

Or, without `dplyr` (same result)

```
df[, sapply(df, function(x) !is.factor(x) | sum(tabulate(x) > 1) <= 1)]
```

This selects all non-factor columns, and factor columns with 1 or less levels which appear more than once.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. Both approaches worked after a slight change. I will edit my post above.

Answer (score 2):

We can loop over the columns, get a `table`, and check whether both the frequencies are greater than 2

```
i1 <- colSums(sapply(df1[-1], function(x) 
       table(factor(x, levels = c("cat", "dog"))))>1) <=1

df1[c(TRUE, i1)]
#  row.name Factor1 Factor4
#1        1     dog     cat
#2        2     dog     dog
#3        3     dog     dog
#4        4     dog     dog
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the `row.name` is a column, so removed the first column from comparison (`df1[-1]`) and concatenated with `TRUE` while subsettting

Comment: Also thank you very much for your help! I tried it, but it did not really work for me. I even added a valid row.name column for the concatenation step, but I still couldn't get it right.

Comment: @plik I created the example based on your post.  So, it is not clear why it is not working for you